# Phase shifting a signal

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, signal-processing, wavelet

I have a signal of the form $s(t)=A(t) \sum cos(\omega_i(t)t +\phi_0) + n(t)$, where $n$ is *gaussian noise*.

Now I want to phase shift this to $A(t) \sum cos(\omega_i(t)t)$ and I am at a loss on how to do this. During lectures / courses I've always done phase shifts simply by multiplying with $e^{i\phi_0}$ (signal is of the form $e^{ix}$).

Is there any way to do this? I'm asking because I am interested in cross-correlating two signals.

**Edit**: [Posted this on signal processing stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/phase-shifting-a-noisy-signal)

Comment: The expression that is your goal contains no explicitly random terms.  Have you perhaps forgotten an additive random term, as in the original expression, or do you intend one of the other parameters such as $A(t)$ or $\omega_i(t)$ to be random?

Answer (score 1):

White noise stays white noise when phase shifted, since it's stationary. Therefore, shifting $s(t)$ (the noisy signal) is equivalent to shifting $s(t) - n(t)$ (the signal without the noise).

In other words: $e^{i \phi_0} n(t)$ is still gaussian noise and you should just ignore the noise while shifting. Probably your teacher wanted you to realize that.

(By the way: this question is probably more related to signal processing than stats and there is a dedicated stackexchange for that on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi Denwid, thanks for the reply! The problem with the phase shift is that I have the signal in real space (so the signal is not in the form of $\sum e^{i\omega_i t+a}$, so I can't phase shift the signal simply by using $e^{i\phi_0}((A(t) \sum cos(\omega_i(t) t+a))-n(t))$. The total signal is the only thing I have so I also can't just transform $cos(x) \rightarrow e^{ix}$. Should I try e.g. transforming the whole signal to frequency space and operate there? 
Do you know of a way to move the question to the other forum? Or shall I delete it and move it there?

Comment: I made a post here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/phase-shifting-a-noisy-signal